# Buttons control Frame Position in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

First off, this is an Actionscript 3 question.

Okay, this is a bit complicated to explain, but I have been searching for a way to make an invisible button, when highlighted, control a movie clip. I have images inside this movie clip that are all separate. When the mouse hovers over the left invisible button, the images scroll right. When the mouse hovers over the right invisible button, the images scroll left. Im unsure if reversing the frames is even possible, or maybe even if you can divide the 120 frames (with the 60th frame being my start) and making the mouse move back by math form? Either way, they are images and buttons. Is there any way of doing ANYTHING like this, even if it means math form, frame form or making the images animate individually and move into positions?

Cheers,
 - Jesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean, but it sounds like you're trying to go back 1 frame?

```
[movieClip].gotoAndStop([movieClip].currentFrame - 1);
```

This would do that I guess. Feel free to comment if that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Its close to what I want. The best way to explain it would be the way Windows 8.1 menu works. I move the mouse to the right and it scrolls right, but I want to move my frames forward and backward. Does that make better sense?

Comment: If you want movieclips to scroll left/right I guess the best way to do this would be to dynamically add/remove children whenever a movieclip goes off the (sides of the) stage. Is there any way you can show me what you mean?

Comment: Or, if the cursor is on the left and you want a movieclip to go back a frame, and if it's on the right and you want it to go forward a frame - Add a variable to the movieclip to tell it what to do (rewind, pause, play), and use Event.ENTER_FRAME with the code in my original answer. Then use MouseEvent.MOUSE_HOVER to set the variable to rewind/play, and MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT to set the variable to pause.

Comment: What would I do to make the movement a particular speed? Like 10 frames per second in rewind?

Comment: To show you what I have made, below is a series of images. Look at the frames and where the positioning is to get a better idea for what I mean.

Frame 60: http://i60.tinypic.com/24pz5vn.png
Frame 37: http://i58.tinypic.com/2hziefp.png
Frame 1: http://i58.tinypic.com/sztrtu.png

Comment: The grey bars are the "invisible" buttons that, when hovered over, I want to make the frames move.

Comment: To make it 10 frames per second, just set flash to run at 10fps. Unless you have a specific reason to have it at a different framerate?

Comment: I'd hate to be a pain, but Im not FULLY up to scratch with the variables part haha. I know how to make one, but what code do I use for it to understand rewind, pause or play. Could you possibly give me an example?

Comment: I've put all the coding and an example of the code being put into use right [here](http://neguidocorp.com/as3examples/framesandarrows.html). You can also download the .fla file if you need help understanding how it works.

Comment: I just got the play working, and stop, however rewind isnt. I will look at your code and file, thanks! Also, I want the scrolling to stop at frame 120 (my last frame) and not go any further when I hover over the right button. (The same for the left.) How would I do that?

Comment: It'll automatically stop at frame 120 unless there are more than 120 frames.

Comment: Wait...nevermind haha It stops automatically! Mate, you are pure AWESOME! I would never have figured that out haha!